# Jquery value between values in array and return object

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to return an object in an array based on an input value.

I have an array called `highestArray` like this:

```
[
  {
    "qty": 50,
    "price": "€4,15",
    "price_excl": "€5,03"
  },
  {
    "qty": 400,
    "price": "€3,93",
    "price_excl": "€4,76"
  },
  {
    "qty": 800,
    "price": "€3,72",
    "price_excl": "€4,50"
  },
  {
    "qty": 1600,
    "price": "€3,45",
    "price_excl": "€4,18"
  }
]
```

​On a button click I want to run a function `changePrice` that changes the price according to the input value, or `goal`.

```
   $('.quantity-btn').on('click', function(){
    var goal = $('.quantity-input input').val();
    changePrice(highestArray, goal )
   });
```

Let's say the input value is `75`. How can I return the object from the array that equals the **lowest nearest** `qty` value in the array?
So if the input value/goal is 75 then the following object should return:

```
{"qty": 50, "price": "€4,15", "price_excl": "€5,03" }
```

When the input value/goal is `799` then this object should return:

```
{"qty": 400,"price": "€3,93", "price_excl": "€4,76" }
```

My function so far looks like this:

```
   function changePrice(array,num){
      var i=0;
      var minDiff=1000;
      var ans;

      for(i in array){
           var m = Math.abs(num - array[i]);
           if(m < minDiff){ 
                  minDiff = m; 
                  ans = array[i]; 
              }
        }
      return ans;
    }
```

When the value is 799 then it returns the object with `qty` 800. I think I'm very close but I just can't get it to work somehow. I've searched this forum thoroughly but can't find a matching asnwer.

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is the array always sorted by price, as in the example?

Comment: @CertainPerformance: It's a dynamically created array and probably it will always start with lowest quantity. So I would say yes :) But does that make a big difference then when we need to check on `qty`?

Comment: `array.slice().reverse().find(({ qty }) => qty <= num)`